# Spanish character on RDLC Reports (Business Central)

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, reportbuilder3.0, dynamics-business-central

I´m trying to run an rdlc report but one of the fields has an spanish character ( ó ) and the report it´s not showing it correctly, it shows like in the image, do you know any solution for that?

I´m only extracting the file from the XML, it only fails in that.